# Introductory Combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck on problem 39 in brualdi  's book Ch-1 4edition. It's: Take any set 2n of points in the plane with no three collinear and then arbitrarily color each point red or blue. Prove that it's always possible to pair up the red points with the blue points by drawing line segments connecting them so that no two of the line segments intersect.         I do not want the solution . I just want to understand the problem.

Comment: which part of the problem do you don't get it?

Comment: Actually, I think you just give me the solution

Comment: Are you supposed to color $n$ points red and $n$ points blue?  Otherwise how do you pair them up if all the points are colored red?  The idea is you draw line segments from each red point to a different blue point.  There are lots of ways to choose which red and blue points are connected.  The idea is to show that at least one of them has no line segments that cross.  For example, you might have four points in a square with two on one side red.  If you draw the two diagonals they cross, but if you draw the two red-blue sides they do not.

Comment: Yeah that's what I got as well. That's why I think maybe I am interpreting it incorrectly. I think I am going to give up on this problem

Comment: I think one has to assume half are red and half are blue.  I believe I see a solution and can give you a hint if you like.

Comment: OK.  Actually,  I wanted to tell that there is a hint in the books as well. It's: Consider a pairing in which the total length of the new line segments is as small as possible. But I just couldn't not get it cause I do not understand the question.